# How do I select what's inside of the this selector? JQuery

Tags: jquery, selector, this

For example, I have a nested list:

```
<ul id="navigation">
    <li id="home">
        <ul id="sub_menus">
            <li id="about_us">
                <div class="same>
                    ... content ...
                </div>
            </li>
            <li id="contact_us">
                <div class="same>
                    ....... content ...
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And I have this JQuery:

```
$('#sub_menus > li').click(function () {
    $action = $('.same').css("display");
        if ($action == "none") {
            $('??????').css("display", "block");
        } else {
            $('??????').css("display", "none");
        }
});
```

What selector would I use to display the div.same when I click on either li#about_us or li#contact_us. If I select the class .same it displays/hides both menus but I only want to display the one with the parent being clicked on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the `div.same` that is a descendant of the LI you clicked, use

```
$(this).find('.same')
```

In your example, what you want is the following:

```
$('#sub_menus > li').click(function () {
    $(this).find('.same').toggle(); // display if hidden, hide if displayed
});
```

If you would rather use `.css()` statements to toggle display (instead of the `.toggle()` shortcut), you can use the following:

```
$('#sub_menus > li').click(function () {
    var same = $(this).find('.same'),
        display = same.css('display');
    same.css('display', display === 'block' ? 'none' : 'block');
});
```

Comment: I like to use CSS to display or hide my items not JQuery but thank you.

Comment: Um, when you use `.css("display", "block")` or `.css("display", "none")` you are using jQuery.  `.toggle()` is just a shortcut that does *exactly the same thing* while saving a few lines of code!

Comment: @Nomad101, `.toggle()` only uses an animation if a duration is specified, unless I am completely misreading the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/.

Comment: @DerekHenderson I am totally the one that misread it. I completely retract that statement.

Comment: @ManuelMedina, I have edited my answer to show code both with `.css()` as you requested and with `.toggle()`. Both should work exactly the same way, by changing the CSS display property, only one is a shortcut for the other.

Comment: I had one small typo, but it works perfectly: http://jsfiddle.net/x7n2a/ and http://jsfiddle.net/x7n2a/1/.

Comment: @ManuelMedina, btw, I fixed one typo in your html (you had `</di>` instead of `</div>`) but you have two other typos which might be affecting things (twice have `<div class="same>` instead of `<div class="same">`).  Check out my two fiddles to see that both methods work just fine, unless we are completely misunderstanding what you want.

Comment: @ManuelMedina I have confirmed that both will work you must have an error elsewhere as Derek suggested. Also to be fair I believe Derek Henderson should get the answer vote since his idea is more perform-ant and fluent.

Comment: @ManuelMedina Ok you need to change your code to listen to the click event on your `h` tags not the `li` that should give you what you want. What actually is happening is the `li` click event is getting overshadowed by the click events for the headings and divs.

Comment: You didn't make the fix I made in my code.  I have updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7VFBq/2/

Comment: @Nomad101, no, his listeners are fine.  If he listens to the headings he'll never toggle the display on, because the heading is inside the hidden div!  He just needs to make the small code correction I suggested above and is in my fiddle.  If he compares the variable `same` to the string `block` it will always be false and therefore always set the css to `display: block`.  He need to change `same` in the comparison to `display`.  And the code then works perfectly.

Comment: Thank you so much for stickying up with me! Derek and @Nomad101

Comment: @ManuelMedina the last line of code is an inline if expresion the code before the `?` is the same thing that is inside the parenthesis in `if(expression)` and the colon seperates the if and else statements so the line is equivalent to `if(display === 'block'){ 'none' } else{ 'block' }`

Comment: @DerekHenderson Yea you are right I rechecked the code and you are entirely right about that. sorry Medina if that sent you in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the event object that is passed to the function handler for the click event. Something like this `$('#sub_menus > li').click(function(event){`

Your code would look like this:

```
$('#sub_menus > li').click(function(event){
    var $item = $(event.target).children("div.same");

    if ($item.css("display") == "none") {
        $item.css("display", "block");
    }   
    else {
        $item.css("display", "none");
    }
});
```

you could also use the `this` keyword in place of the `event.target`, however the event also stores information like location and other event properties.

Comment: For some reason this works only to display but not to hide my items?

Comment: @ManuelMedina HAHA edited had display set to block for both. check my edit.

Comment: @Nomad101, this is an extremely convoluted way of doing things, don't you think?  I mean, `event.target` instead of `this`, really?

Comment: @DerekHenderson I state explicitly in the answer that you can easily replace the `event.target` with `this`.

Comment: haha silly me didnt see that. now it works 3/4. Now it displays/hides one of the menus but it only displays but doesn't hide the other one :/

Comment: @Nomad101, yes, you do.  Just seems a bit convoluted and unnecessary to even consider `event.target`, but I suppose in the interests of completeness...

Comment: @DerekHenderson I find a lot of people just completely glaze over the fact that the event object even exists and a lot of people end up looking for things that the eventObject has implicitly, such as the location of the click, or key of the keypress.

Comment: @ManuelMedina hmmm that is odd behavior. so both can be displayed on the click of the `li` but one does not get hidden on a subsequent click on its parent?

Comment: exactly, on my actual code I have 4 menus and only 1 displays/hides as suppose to and the rest just show up when clicked but dont hide.

Comment: hmmm I think this has to do with the `$action` variable that you are using. Why exactly are you using it and what is its intended purpose, if it is to determine the display currently set for the div.same you should change the selector like I have it set in my recent edit. Although I am starting to think that @DerekHenderson may have the best solution for you.

Comment: hmmm can you try it in chrome with the integrated development tools and step through the javascript and see what happens. That will give you a really good idea of why its not working correctly. If you want you can use FireBug in Firefox if youd like.